# AngularJS Karma test - Resolve object passed into controller is undefined when testing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

We are using ui-router 0.2.10.

I am injecting a resolve object as a parameter into my controller, which is then setting a scope variable in the controller. It works perfectly on the app like so:

**state provider**

```
$stateProvider.state('myState', {
      resolve:{
         foo:  function(){
            return 'bar';
         },
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: 'index.html',
      controller: 'FooCtrl'
   })
```

**controller**

```
app.Controllers.controller('FooCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', 'foo',
    function ($scope, $state, $log, Zone, foo) {
        $scope.testVar = foo
        console.log($scope.testVar);
    }])
```

'Bar' is then logged to the console as expected in Chrome.

But when running tests using Karma, the resolve object is now undefined, which fails the test. Here is the test code:

```
describe('controllers', function(){

  var $rootScope, 
      $scope,
      $state

  beforeEach(module('app'))

  beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
    $state = $injector.get('$state')
    $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope')
    $scope = $rootScope.$new()
    $controller = $injector.get('$controller')
  }))

  it('FooCtrl should exist', inject( function() {
    $state.go('myState')
    $rootScope.$apply()

    $controller = $controller('FooCtrl', {
      '$scope': $scope
    })
    $rootScope.$apply()

    assert.equal($scope.testVar, "bar", "these strings are equal")
  }))
})
```

This error is presented (the resolve object in my case is called resolvedRouteModels):

```
[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: fooProvider <- foo
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-build.2921+sha.02c0ed2/$injector/unpr?p0=fooProvider%20%3C-%20foo
```

Any help would be much appreciated, and please let me know if you have encountered this problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17567894/unit-testing-controller-which-uses-state-transitionto

Answer (score 11):

When you instantiate your controller, Angular usually can figure out how to satisfy the controller's dependencies. In this case, it doesn't know about UI-Router's "resolve" functionality.

One way to address this is to supply this dependency yourself in the test, the same way you are passing in the scope to the controller:

```
var foo = 'bar'; // whatever
$controller = $controller('FooCtrl', {$scope: $scope, foo: foo} );
```

Note, you could also create a mock `$state` object and pass that into the controller the same way, if you wanted to incorporate that into your tests.

Comment: What if: `foo: function(){return $http(...);}` calls $http data, then do we have to mock the http request as well?

Comment: No need to mock the HTTP request. If the return value of the `foo` function is a promise (which is what the `$http` functions return), then UI-Router will wait to inject `foo` into the controller until that promise is resolved. So if the end result of the HTTP request is an Array, you can just make `foo` be an Array in the test.

Comment: To be more clear: In the real app UI-Router waits for the HTTP request to be completed so it can inject the resulting value into the controller. In the test, you bypass the HTTP request all together and just inject the value that you would have gotten from the HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

my assumption is your Angular set up is perfect, if that's the case, you might want to test your code this way. I've used Jasmine 2 syntax.

```
describe('Foo Controller', function() {
    var  $scope, $state, controller, Zone, foo, $log;
    beforeEach(module('app'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($controller) {
        $scope = {};
        $state = {};
        $log = {};
        Zone = {};
        foo = {};
        controller = $controller;
    }));

    it('should log the value foo', function() {
        spyOn(console, 'log');
        controller('FooCtrl', { $scope, $state, $log, Zone, foo });
        expect($scope.testVar).toEqual({});
        expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith({});
    });

    it('should log the value foo', function() {
        spyOn(console, 'log');
        // You could change the value of foo i.e.
        foo = 'create more spies than fbi';
        controller('FooCtrl', { $scope, $state, $log, Zone, foo });
        expect($scope.testVar).toEqual('create more spies than fbi');
        expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith('create more spies than fbi');
    });

});
```

Once again I hope this helps. Peace.