# Mock a $stage.go transition

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, jasmine

I have a controller with an activate() method:

```
function CustomerController(customerFactory, $state, $stateParams) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.getCustomer = getCustomer;

    activate();

    function activate() {
        if($state.is('customer-view')) vm.getCustomer($stateParams.id);
    }

    function getCustomer(id) {
        return customerFactory.getCustomer(id)
            .then(getCustomerComplete)
            .catch(getCustomerFailed);

        function getCustomerComplete(response) {
            return vm.customer = response;
        }

        function getCustomerFailed(error) {
            return vm.error = error;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to test, using jasmine, that on `$state.go('customer-view', {id: 1})` the getCustomer(id) function has been called.

Here is my test:

```
it("should be called", inject(function($state) {
    spyOn(vm, 'getCustomer');
    $state.go('customer-view', {id: 1});
    expect(vm.getCustomer).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
}));
```

And the test returns "Expected spy getCustomer to have been called once. It was called 0 times."

PS: the code above is working, I just don't know how to test it.

EDIT:

Here a bigger example of my spec file:

```
describe("app.customers controller", function () {

    var $controller, customers, deferred, customerFactoryMock, vm, $rootScope, $q;

    beforeEach(function () {
        module('app.customers');
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$rootScope_, _$controller_, _$q_, _customerFactory_) {
        customerFactoryMock = _customerFactory_;
        $controller = _$controller_;
        vm = $controller("CustomerController", {customerFactory: customerFactoryMock});
        $q = _$q_;
        deferred = $q.defer();
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        customers = [{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}];
    }));

    describe("getCustomer(id)", function () {
        it("should call the factory method", function () {
            spyOn(customerFactoryMock, 'getCustomer').and.returnValue(deferred.promise);
            vm.getCustomer(1);
            expect(customerFactoryMock.getCustomer).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        });

        it("should be called", inject(function($state) {
            spyOn(vm, 'getCustomer');
            $state.go('customer-view', {id: 1});
            expect(vm.getCustomer).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        }));

        it("should have a customer on resolved", function () {
            spyOn(customerFactoryMock, 'getCustomer').and.returnValue(deferred.promise);
            deferred.resolve({"id": 1});
            vm.getCustomer(1);
            $rootScope.$digest();
            expect(vm.customer).toBeDefined();
            expect(vm.customer.id).toEqual(1);
        });

        it("should return an error message on reject", function () {
            spyOn(customerFactoryMock, 'getCustomer').and.returnValue(deferred.promise);
            deferred.reject('this is a reason');
            vm.getCustomer();
            $rootScope.$digest();
            expect(vm.error).toBeDefined();
            expect(vm.error).toBe('this is a reason');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you initiated the controller in your test? Could you paste test code in its entirety?

Comment: Yeah, where is vm coming from in the test?

Comment: I've added the spec in its entirety, check the EDIT part at the end.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unit testing controller which uses $state.transitionTo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17567894/unit-testing-controller-which-uses-state-transitionto)

Comment: I do not think it is the same. My state 'customer-view' is already defined. What I want is to simulate (or do) the `$state.go('customer-view', {id: 1})`. I think I missed something like $rootScope.$apply(), but even with it I have an error: Unexpected request: GET customer/view.html.